# F# and xna font problems

Tags: f#, xna

I decided to learn F# a while ago and to make it a bit more fun for myself I want to use XNA. There is only once issue I cannot seem to get over, and it has to do with the content pipeline. Basically, to draw a string I need a font. To get a font I need the content pipeline. But since I am using F# I cant seem to be able to access the content pipeline at all. So how do I draw text?

Note: To get F# and XNA running I just added the references to the XNA assemblies in Visual Studio. Dont know if there is another way, have not been able to find it.

Take care,
Kerr

Comment: For things like this the best way is to create a minimal C# project that does all the font/graphics stuff and then add it as a reference to the F# project that does all the work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the [special features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11755294/165500) of the XNA "**Game Project**" and "**Game Library Project**" templates is that they are able to hold a "Content Reference" to an XNA "**Content Project**". (Note that you will need XNA Game Studio installed.)

When you build the game [library] project, it will invoke the build of all the content projects that it references. The reason that the content projects don't get compiled independently is that they can be built for different platforms (Xbox, Windows, etc) and for different profiles (Reach, HiDef) - these options are specified by the referencing projects (of which there can be many).

The simple way to do a content build for a non-XNA-Game project type is simply to simply create an empty "Windows Game Library Project" (or whichever platform you are targeting). Add your content reference to that library. And then reference that library from your project.

Visual Studio is clever enough to copy the content into your project's output directory, when it copies the empty DLL.

---

Another option might be to use `MSBuild.exe` to directly compile the content project. You will have to specify the platform and profile yourself, like so:

```
/property:XNAContentPipelineTargetPlatform=Windows;XNAContentPipelineTargetProfile=Reach
```

Comment: So I just add a reference to that library (more specifically, the compiled assembly) like I did when I referenced XNA? Or did you mean something else? Not that experienced in .NET yet so I still have a lot to learn. And thanks for your response :).

Comment: You should be able to right-click your F# project and then "Add Reference". Choose the shim project from the "Project" tab (I'm not sure it will work if you just reference the compiled assembly directly - I suspect it won't).

Comment: That might be a problem. I only have Visual Studio Shell and Visual C# Express. Visual Studio Shell allows me to work with F# but not C#, and Visual C# Express allows me to work with C# but not F#. Dont know if I can reference a C# project with an F# one. Will have to take a closer look at it, though.

Comment: I think that, in this case, your only option might be to invoke `MSBuild` as a post-build step, and set the `OutDir` property so that it outputs to the same directory as your F# project.

Comment: I got it to work finally :). I simply compiled a basic C# XNA project and then copied over the xnb file for the font. A bit hacky but at least it worked. Thanks for your help, wouldnt have figured that out otherwise.